# Deleting a record in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and I am making a project. and in the project I have a table with records. I also have a delete button in every row of the table. When I click this button I want it to delete the record, however, it is not working. When I click the delete button it sends me to a different page and gives me a 404 error. I really appreciate if someone could help me with my problem.

My view :

```
<body>
    <div class="spelers">
    @if (count ($spelers) > 0)
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th scope="col">Selectie</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </thead>
        @foreach ($spelers as $speler)
            <tr><td><a>{{{ $speler->speler_naam }}}</a></td><td><img src="../../img/edit.png" alt=""></a></td><td><a href="delete/{{ $speler->id }}"><img src="../../img/delete2.png" alt=""></a></td></tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
    @else
        Er zijn helaas geen clubs beschikbaar
    @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller :

```
public function Destroy($id)
{
    SpelerSelectie::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect ('/');
}
```

My routes :

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'VoetbalController@Destroy');
```

Comment: Share the link which is generated for deleting posted. I think its not relative url that is giving you 404.

Comment: <a href="{{ url('delete/').$speler->id}}">  =>  replace this and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do `delete` without a `/` the link will append the current page you are on. So if you are on `/test`, then the url will be `/test/delete`.

To make sure you always end up on the correct url path, you can simply generate the url in the blade file based on the action. It will look like this:

**Change**

```
<a href="delete/{{ $speler->id }}">
```

**To**

```
<a href="{{ action('VoetbalController@destroy', $speler->id) }}">
```

You can now also change the route and the link will still be correctly rendered.

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: Glad to hear! @stefandeboer

Answer (score 1):

Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes.

Route :

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', 'VoetbalController@destory')->name('voetbal.destroy');
```

Call :

```
<a href="{{ route('voetbal.destroy', $speler->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: best answer imo, because named routes allow you to easily change the actual URL name by changing only 1 line of code

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<a href="delete/{{ $speler->id }}">
```

To

```
<a href="/delete/{{ $speler->id }}">
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your url is not being generated properly.

Use this helper method for generation urls.

```
url()
```

`<a href="{{ url('delete/') . $speler->id }}">`

Comment: I don't know why but this method is not working for me. its still giving me a 404 error.